# Counting functions with the condition that any periodic points must be fixed points.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Suppose there is a function $X =  \{1,..., n\}$.

I would like to count the functions $f: \{1,..., n\} \rightarrow \{1, ..., n\}$ with the following condition:

Each periodic point in the function is a fixed point.

A fixed point is periodic point where $f(x) = x $   [period 1].

---

I first attempted to count the number of functions *without* fixed points (with the inclusion-exclusion principle in mind), but I realized that by the wording of the question, it is probably not necessary that there be any fixed points in the function.

So far, I know that any point must either be sent to itself, or not. But I cannot find a method to count every function, any pointers?

Comment: You count the functions, not the number of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another point $n+1$ and consider the labelled trees on this augmented set of $n+1$ elements. It is well-known that there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ of them (see [Cayley’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)).

Now consider these trees as rooted at $n+1$, and map each point to its ancestor on the way to this root, mapping the points whose ancestor is $n+1$ to themselves. This is a bijection between the labelled trees on $n+1$ elements and the functions you want to count (via a bijection  between the labelled trees on $n+1$ elements and the rooted forests of labelled trees on $n$ elements). Thus the desired count is $(n+1)^{n-1}$.

See also [OEIS sequence A000272](https://oeis.org/A000272).

Comment: Thanks, that was a very nice solution, I didnt think about using graphs to solve this!

Comment: I just thought of something though: does this take into account if the function has no fixed points? Then I would not be able to connect any node to the $n+1$ root.

Comment: @sjrr00: That's impossible. A function on a finite set without fixed points must have cycles. Apply $f$ iteratively to any point; you must end up either at a fixed point or in a cycle.

Comment: you're right, thanks for clarifying!